# WordPress 6.3, Navigation Menu has been created but I am unable to select it in Elementor where I want to select menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

In the latest WordPress 6.3 update, I've encountered an issue with the navigation menu integration within Elementor. Despite having successfully created a navigation menu, I'm currently facing challenges when attempting to select it within the Elementor page builder interface. This issue is a departure from the intuitive menu selection process I was accustomed to in previous WordPress versions.

My primary objective is to seamlessly integrate the designated navigation menu into the Elementor platform. However, the apparent lack of menu selection options has posed a hindrance to this process.

Navigating through the elements and options available in Elementor, I've been unable to identify a straightforward means to select the specific menu for use on my pages. This discrepancy between my prior experience and the present functionality within Elementor has left me seeking a solution to ensure that the menu created in WordPress can be effortlessly incorporated into my Elementor-designed pages.